# IsInitializing WCF

Tags: wcf

For a service contract definition like following,

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="MySevices.WCFService")]
public interface IBasicService
```

And following OperationContracts,

```
[OperationContract(IsInitiating=true)]
string InitializeData(int value);

[OperationContract()]
string CheckData(int value, String userName);
```

Why don't I get an error message when I just call **CheckData**?

I am using NetTCPBinding.

**UPDATE:**
Oh, This property is used to in case we want to force our clients to call the method which has "IsInitiating" to true first. Since default value of IsInitiatingis true, we need to set this property value to false explicitly. In such a case, if we call methods with IsInitiating = false with one which is initializing we get an error.

Comment: If you were able to answer your own question, please post it as an answer.  You will then be able to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the default value for `IsInitiating` is true. Even if it were false, it would only make sense if you were talking about sessionful contracts. Unless you set the `SessionMode` property in the `[ServiceContract]` attribute to `SessionMode.Required`, WCF won't let the service start.